# Is it possible for a sandboxed Mac app to write to the global defaults domain?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults, sandbox, foundation, appstore-sandbox

Is there any way to allow a sandboxed Mac app to read *and* write keys to the global user defaults domain (`NSGlobalDomain`/`.globalDomain`)? Right now, the writes are failing and this error is being logged in the console.

```
[User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (...) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002df5300> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
```

I'd like the keep the app sandboxed, though Mac App Store compliance isn't a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following to the app's entitlements file.

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.shared-preference.read-write</key>
<string>kCFPreferencesAnyApplication</string>
```

[See here for the docs on this entitlements key](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW4)